# "Class 'JToolbarHelper' not found" error with no control over joomla

Tags: joomla

So I just opened Joomla today and got an error stating that the jtoolbarHelper is missing. I went to [this](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/22874) GitHub forum where every other forum seems to direct me to and it states that I need to alter files on the server-side by restoring backup. Sadly I do not have access to the server and I do not know if they have make backups. I have contacted my superior with this issue (hopefully she can get in touch with the server admins and they can revert the changes) but is there any other solution till they reply. I've tried accessing the files on Joomla in the hopes I can change them but that error screen has me basically locked out.

Comment: Come join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to resolve this issue from cPanel by upgrading the Joomla version there (as opposed to using the admin page which doesn't work in this case).

Hope that helps